# How to use "impressionist" gem in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails dev and is looking to use https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist but not able to figure out how to use it looking at its documentation. I have done the migration and when trying to put

```
class ArticlesController < InheritedResources::Base
  impressionist
end
```

OR

```
class ArticlesController < InheritedResources::Base
  impressionist :actions=>[:show,:index]
end
```

it is throwing no method found error. **I am unsure which code needs to be put in model, which to be in controller and which to be in views** to see view_count, any help ?

Comment: show the error please

Comment: @Guy - I am putting the code in controller and getting "undefined method `impressionist' for ArticlesController:Class", do I need to put some code in Article.rb model too ?

Comment: @iCyborg the documentation on the Github page is very thorough. Have you put `is_impressionable` in the models you want to track?

Comment: @RobinFisher - Now i have put is_impressionable in article.rb but getting this error "undefined local variable or method `is_impressionable' for #<Class:0xb86ab68>", in my controller I have "  impressionist :actions=>[:show,:index] 
  @widget.impressionist_count(:filter=>:all)" and in views, I have "<%= article.impressionist_count(:filter=>:all) %>"

Comment: I can't tell for sure but it might be an issue of `InheritedResources` and `impressionist` that don't play well ...

Comment: @iCyborg try restarting your server !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first question was a type

and as for your second question (inside the comment) the easiest but very efficient way would be

```
 in the view:
 <% @pages.each do |page| %>
   <%= page.impressionist_count %> 
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Hi Guy, I have put this in index.html.erb, but getting this error "undefined method `impressionist_count' for nil:NilClass", surprisingly, /page/1 are showing the view count!

Comment: you meant in the controller ? I have put "impressionist :actions=>[:show,:index]", I am very surprised that it the show.html.erb is working but not the index.html.erb

Comment: yes in the controller, you might have to edit inherited resources to have a `@pages` instance variables ...

Comment: Aah, @Guy yes, it was this stupid InheritedResources, I changed it to ApplicationController and created all the methods, now it is working, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Impression` as a model to query stuff, just like normal models. For example,

```
Impression.where(user_id: 12).length
```

I find this is handy if you need some advanced queries.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation does not specify to re-start server.  This is not obvious as it does not apply to all gems, however it is required for impressionist.

Comment: It's required of gems that work with your database (as far as I can tell)